# Reactive forms validating at least one field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Looking for a way to use reactive forms in angular to validate 2 required fields and at least one of ten other fields.So we have fields 1 and 2 are required, and at least one of the 3 through 12 must be selected. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It would help us a lot if you would post some code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the 3-12 into a form group and write a custom validator against the form group.

Here is an example of a custom validator I wrote to compare "email" and "confirm email" elements in a form group:

```
function emailMatcher(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
    let emailControl = c.get('email');
    let confirmControl = c.get('confirmEmail');

    if (emailControl.pristine || confirmControl.pristine) {
      return null;
    }

    if (emailControl.value === confirmControl.value) {
        return null;
    }
    return { 'match': true };
 }
```

The form was then defined as follows:

```
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        emailGroup: this.fb.group({
            email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+')]],
            confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required],
        }, {validator: emailMatcher}),
        phone: ''
    });
```

You could do something similar with putting your elements 3 - 12 into a form group and then writing a custom validator that is assigned to that group.

Comment: Would you handle match: true like a flag in the html?

Comment: Thanks after some testing i found to check  for the returned value as an error message. For nested forms its parentform.controls['childform'].haserror('expectedvalue')

Comment: Or you can use `.get()` as I showed in my emailMatcher function above.